# Troubleshooting AMD graphics card w/ artifacts and BSODs

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

I am running a fully updated copy of Windows 7 Ultimate on a self-built PC with AMD Phenom II X4 945 3.0 gHz CPU with 8.0 GB RAM and a discrete AMD Radeon HD 5570 graphics card.

A problem I've been experiencing is that my screen often shows strange artifacts (coloured blocks at random places) or textures during regular use. Also, (1) the automatic assessment for the Windows Experience Index fails with my screen blacking out and coming back with a driver crashed error, and (2) when I play a game like Call of Duty the display would freeze, black out, and return constantly.

I thought it may be a problem with the default driver for my graphics card installed by Windows Update, so I downloaded and installed the latest official Catalyst drivers from AMD. However, with the updated driver I get more artifacts on screen, even basic stuff like using Firefox fails with crashed driver errors, and I often get BSODs even before I get to the Windows 7 login screen. Therefore I have temporarily reverted back to the "default" Windows Update drivers.

Is this a physical problem with my graphics card (i.e. it is broken and I need to replace it), or is this another problem? I'd appreciate any help with troubleshooting this problem. Thank you!

BTW, I ran memtest86+ and here are the results (no error):
[image]

Comment: Have you run memtest86+ yet?

Comment: One of the easiest things to do is, if possible, borrow a graphic unit from some one else and test it! And what are the messages on the BSOD's ?

Comment: Heat is a likely culprit. Check fans and dust buildup.

Comment: Thanks for the comments thus far: (1) I ran memtest86+ for six hours and there doesn't seem to be any problems (though I don't understand a lot of the output, see my screenshot). (2) I will try to get another graphics card to test. (3) The BSOD only appears for about a second, but if it happens again I will try to read it somehow.

Comment: when the BSOD occurs it writes a dump with the check code to disk, bluescreenview can read the file and give you the code, as well as the driver or program that caused it

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a faulty graphics card.
It seems, that the problem gets worse as soon as there is load on the Graphics Adapter.

There can be several Reasons for this:
1. Cooling problem
Solution: Check, if the Air inside the case is circulated properly and that the cooling system is working and not clogged with dust

2. Power problem
   What are the power requirements for the graphics card?
   What does your Power Supply say about power that it can deliver on the +12V rail?
   How old is your power supply?
   Solution: Try another Power supply
3. Your graphics card is faulty
   Try to get another card (preferably of the same type) and test

Comment: I have had several low end graphics cards with really tiny fans that have failed, Asus AMD/ATI cards in particular dont last too long.